# Determine whether $f_x(1,0)$ and $f_x(0,0)$ exists with $f(x,y) = x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be a function with $f(x,y) = x\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Determine whether $f_x(1,0)$ and $f_x(0,0)$ exists, where $f_x$ denotes the first partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$.

**EDIT:**

**Attempt:**
First of all, we have
$$f_x(x,y) = \frac{\partial (x\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial (x)}{\partial x} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + x \frac{\partial (\sqrt{x^2+y^2})}{\partial x} = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} + x \frac{2x}{2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{2x^2+y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
Hence, $f_x(1,0) = \frac{2(1)^2+0^2}{\sqrt{(1)^2+0^2}} = 2$.

For find $f_x(0,0)$, we use the definition:
$$f_x(0,0) = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h,0) - f(0,0)}{h} = 
\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{h|h|}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} |h| = 0.$$

Hence, $f_x(1,0)=2$ and $f_x(0,0)=0$.

Does this works?

Comment: No, this is wrong. Apply definition for $f_x(0,0)$. Actually, $f_x(0,0)=0$.

Comment: Does my edit true?

Comment: Yes, it is fine now.

Comment: Your calculation of $f_x(x,y)$ has a mistake in the denominator the very last step. (When it's corrected, you should have for example $f_x(2,0)=4$, $f_x(-3,0)=6$).

Comment: @Milten Spotted now. Thanks for the correction.